# Confused with git-push

Tags: git

I faced to a situation that puzzles me but I guess the answer is very simple, it is just I can't see it... Hopefully someone can help me

I have a git repo. git-status says that I have 4 commits queued:

```
]$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 4 commits.
#

nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

So I do git-push (`git push origin`) and then it looks fine, i.e. then I have nothing to push. But when I pull (or fetch + merge) the repo in another directory, the changes don't show up.

Moreover, I can pull from the remote into the local directory (`git pull origin`) which results with:

```
 + a4ac30f...10164ca master     -> origin/master  (forced update)
Already up-to-date.
```

and after that I am again 4 commits ahead, i.e. in the same situation I've started. So I can repeat the two commands:

```
git push origin
```

which always results in:

```
]$ git push origin -v
Pushing to http://myserver.com/src.git/myrepo
Fetching remote heads...
  refs/
  refs/heads/
  refs/tags/
Everything up-to-date
```

and

```
git pull origin
```

whose result is always as quoted above infinite number of times and nothing happens, after the first one I am always "`Everything up-to-date`" and after the second one I am always "`ahead of 'origin/master' by 4 commits`"

In both local repositories Fetch URL and Push  URL are the same; `git remote show origin` says:

```
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    git-svn tracked
    master  tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (fast-forwardable)
```

Best,
Tim

Comment: Do you have `push.default` set to something unusual?

Comment: I use default push.default (I haven't defined anything for it by myself)

Comment: `git push origin` prints "Everything up-to-date", right? If you examine your history (`git log --graph` or `gitk`) do you see your master four commits linearly ahead of origin/master?

Comment: Yes, git push origin prints "Everything up-to-date" and Yes, master four commits linearly ahead of origin/master

Comment: Can you add the output of `git push` to your question?

Comment: also how about a screenshot of `gitk --all`?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I solved it! The problem was that some previous `push` didn't go correctly and the remote was screwed up. I logged into the remote server (which is WebDAV-based) and run `chown -R wwwrun src.git`. Then the very next push did the job

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your master branch is not set up to track origin/master, and therefore `git push` is ignoring it entirely.  Try `git push origin master` to tell it specifically which branch to push.

Comment: The submitted output of "git status" makes me doubt your explanation.  It says "Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 4 commits."  Doesn't that message imply that the branch is set up to track origin/master?

Comment: This is possible.  But until the OP tries the command I've listed, we can only guess what `git push origin` is actually doing -- it doesn't look like it's doing anything at all.